# Job shop scheduling with only one operation for each job

Tags: optimization, computer-science, integer-programming, operations-research

I am searching for some literature on my problem, where each job $J_j$ is assigned to only one machine, only two machines can run at once, and the process time on the two machines depend on the combinations of the jobs $\{J_j, J_i\}$.
I have considered a matching problem, but the objective changes and is more suited for a scheduling problem.
Does anyone know any literature that might help me?